# Saving input history from Entry

Tags: python, tkinter, calculator

Alright so I'm building a calculator in python and so far have only built the sum function. Building functions isn't what I'm stuck at tho. I'm building my calculator trying to replicate Windows 10 UWP Calculator behaviour. 
My code kinda does the same that it only takes one input at a time and calculates the sum using the current input and the previous answer. Here's the code I've written:

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()

ans = 0
tocalculate = tk.IntVar()

entry = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=tocalculate)

entry.pack()

def Sum():
    global ans
    ans+=tocalculate.get()
    tocalculate.set(ans)

ansLabel = tk.Label(root, textvariable=tocalculate)
ansLabel.pack()

button_calc = tk.Button(root, text="Calculate", command=Sum)
button_calc.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

It has a few quirks but the logic works. Now, the question that I wanted to ask was that in Windows 10 UWP Calculator when you start calculating it saves your history and shows it in a label above (like the screenshot I've attached). How do I do this using Python and Tkinter?
[Screenshot of UWP Calculator to show you what I mean](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qWbNs.jpg)

I'm fairly new to all this so any and all help will be appreciated.

Comment: I think this is too broad. Which part of showing history are you stuck on exactly? Ask that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add another global variable **var** for storing the calculations in string format, and instead of `ansLabel` displaying **tocalculate** set it to display **var**

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()

ans = 0
var =''   # <-- this will store the calculations in string format
tocalculate = tk.IntVar()
toshow = tk.IntVar()  # <-- This label will display history i.e contents of var

entry = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=tocalculate)

entry.pack()

def Sum():
    global ans
    global var
    v=tocalculate.get()
    var = var+"+"+str(v) 
    ans += v
    tocalculate.set(ans)
    toshow.set(var)

ansLabel = tk.Label(root, textvariable=toshow)
ansLabel.pack()

button_calc = tk.Button(root, text="Calculate", command=Sum)
button_calc.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Also, modified the `Sum` function above, it will store `var = previous value of var + new value entered in textbox` in string format, for substraction replace `+` with `-` and like wise for others

Above code gives [image: this]